# How i can get these from database using mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, substring

I have one table with like did and patientid. here did is doctors id and patient id is for patient.

Now i have to retrieve records according to doctor.

Here the query is patient id like 12/2456. here 12 means 2012.

How i can pick up all rows with id only leaving 12 (year)?

Is it possible to pick up like that ?

table is like

```
did pid 
101 12/3492
101 12/6789
```

now needed output like

```
did pid 
101 3492
101 6789
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select did , substring_index(pid ,'/',-1) pid from table
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help

```
select did,SUBSTRING_INDEX(patient id, '/', -1) pid
from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can build the function like this:

```
SELECT did, RIGHT(pid, LENGTH(pid) - LOCATE('/',pid)) pid
FROM Table
```